# Does Catan expansion edition have to match base game edition?

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

I have the [English fourth edition 2007 base game of Settlers of Catan](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/23765/english-fourth-edition-2007). Are current editions of the expansion, specifically [Catan: Seafarers English edition 2015](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/267045/english-edition-2015), compatible with this base set?

Comment: I believe the differences are mostly in the provided rules and (depending on version) color of player tokens. It should be unproblematic to use expansions cross version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the 5th edition of Catan came out, I remember reading an official source (Catan FAQ) explaining that it would be completely backwards compatible. The only source I can find right now is [this one](http://www.gamenguide.com/articles/20394/20150211/international-toy-fair-2015-news-updated-version-of-catan-demoed-at-mayfair-booth-this-weekend.htm):

> The 5th edition will also be fully backwards compatible to the previous 4th edition and will feature a more cohesive art style throughout all 4th and 5th edition expansions.

It looks a bit odd though, using different editions. So at that time I decided to buy all the old sets while they were still available. It's functionally possible to combine different editions into 1 game, but not aesthetically correct :)